# OS X In App fetch product information always returns invalidProductIdentifiers

Tags: objective-c, macos, in-app-purchase

I want to make an in app purchase on MacOS. I worked close with the IAP guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW9

In iTunes Connect I have added and configured the products on my App.

During App Start in applicationDidFinishLauching I want to fetch the product information. With this snippet:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray: _productIdentifieres]];
_productRequest = request;
_productRequest.delegate = self;
[_productRequest start];
```

The array _productIdentifiers is a List of my productID I want to fetch from the AppStore.

But I only get a list of invalidProductIndentifiers. The Response.Products list is always empty.

So- why will I not get a list of Products (SKProduct)?

Hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking and I don't see the question.  Can you restate what help you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case - it was absolute essential to have the same BundleID AND Bundle Version as the product in AppStore.